# Bootstrap grid col , form-group css :before not applying

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any option to add css :before to .col and .form-groups?
I tried to add a new css but it just don't applying.

The mock is as follow.

CSS

```
.fg-steps {
position: relative;
}

.fg-steps:before {
    background: black;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0;
    left: -10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="fg_parentStatus" class="form-group fg-steps">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***:before*** and ***:after*** rules requires ***content*** property.

Answer (score 2):

':before' and ':after' do not work without `content` property.

change your code to

```
.fg-steps {
  position: relative;
}

.fg-steps:before {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help always :)